# Downsample a wav recording python

Tags: python

Downsample the recording by a factor of 10, i.e. select every 10th
sample of the recorded signal and throw away the rest. how would you downsample a wav audio using slicing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this page on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy.signal as sps
import os

new_rate = 16000
path = "ENTER THE WAV FILENAME"
sampling_rate, data = wavfile.read(path)

samples = round(len(data) * float(new_rate) / sampling_rate)
new_data = sps.resample(data, samples)

wavfile.write("downsampled_wav.wav", new_rate, new_data)
```